LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE when trying to control volume using libusb
I am trying to write a small C program to read and adjust the volume of a USB DAC (Apple USB-C to 3.5mm Dongle). I have been using this document as a reference, but have encountered an issue that I cannot seem to work around. I am receiving a LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE response for my requests.
libusb_control_transfer(handle, 0b10100001, 0x81, 0x0200, 0x0200, mesg, 2, 500); is the line I am using, the bmRequestType, bRequest comes from the document on page 68, wValue is 0x02 (VOLUME_CONTROL) with a lower 0 byte, wIndex comes from sniffing wireshark during a volume change (I have a feeling this is where I am failing, however I do not understand how the Terminal ID is sourced), mesg is 2 0x00 bytes, and wLength is 2. The full program is below.
#include <assert.h>
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    libusb_context *context;
    libusb_device_handle *handle;
    libusb_device *device;
    
    libusb_device **devs;
    ssize_t num_devs;
    
    int i;
    
    struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
    unsigned char buffer[256];
    
    assert(!libusb_init(&context));
    
    num_devs = libusb_get_device_list(context, &devs);
    if (num_devs < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error getting device list\n");
        libusb_exit(context);
        return 1;
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < num_devs; ++i) {
        libusb_device *dev = devs[i];
        struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
        int r = libusb_get_device_descriptor(dev, &desc);
        if (r < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to get device descriptor\n");
            continue;
        }
        if(desc.idVendor == 0x05ac && desc.idProduct == 0x110a){
            device = dev;
        }
    }
    
    assert(!libusb_get_device_descriptor(device, &desc));
    printf("Vendor ID: %04x\n", desc.idVendor);
    printf("Product ID: %04x\n", desc.idProduct);

    assert(libusb_open(device, &handle) == 0);
    device = libusb_get_device(handle);
    
    assert(libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(handle, desc.iManufacturer, buffer, 256) >= 0);
    printf("Manufacturer: %s\n", buffer);
    assert(libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(handle, desc.iProduct, buffer, 256) >= 0);
    printf("Product: %s\n", buffer);
    if (libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(handle, desc.iSerialNumber, buffer, 256) >= 0)
        printf("Serial No: %s\n", buffer);
    libusb_detach_kernel_driver(handle, 0);
    libusb_claim_interface(handle, 0);
    
    int result = libusb_control_transfer(handle, 0b10100001, 0x81, 0x0200, 0x0200, mesg, 2, 500);
    printf(libusb_error_name(result));
    printf("%d", result);
    printf("\n");
    
    libusb_release_interface(handle, 0);
    libusb_attach_kernel_driver(handle, 0);
    libusb_exit(context);
}


What return codes are libusb_detach_kernel_driver() and libusb_claim_interface() returning?

Thanks @Gordon, I just checked and both are returning 0. I now have 2 assert statements to ensure that both are returning code 0 as well.

Huh, both those functions return -3 = LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS - Access denied (insufficient permissions) for me.  Ah, you must be running as root. If I do that I get LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE = -9 too.

Yes, I had to run as root to avoid error -3, but have yet to figure this issue out. I think my next course of action should be to try with a different USB DAC to see if I can narrow down this issue to being Apple specific or something with my code. Thanks for your help

Is it possible your code isn't working because you're using UAC 1.0 commands on a UAC 2.0 Audio device?

Ignore that comment.

I think your bRequest should be 0x1 instead of 0x81:
int result = libusb_control_transfer(handle, 0b10100001 /* bmRequest */, 0x1 /* bRequest */, 0x0200 /* wValue */, 0x0200 /* wIndex */, mesg, 2 /* wLength */, 500);

I can't quote UAC 1.0 at you right now, but it's what I see in wireshark and your code succeeds, resulting in a volume that matches what I see in Audio MIDI Setup.app.

Thank you! Although I am still a bit confused, it seems to be working when I check wireshark, and I receive a response of 2 bytes. My next concern is related to the fact that it seems my code is sending 0x00ec instead of 0x0000 like I had intended, but I think this is more related to my inexperience with C, because if I set the volume in ALSA it returns 0000 as expected.

The response IS two bytes, little endian. Start a new question!
